# Substracting Dates in Javascript return a negative number

Tags: javascript, date, google-analytics, gettime

I am using the TimeTracker.js from [link text](http://www.advanced-web-metrics.com) to track Page Load times and put them in Google Analytics. Basically what it does is record a start time, and once the page loads it records a end time and then subtracts. These are recored using `(new Date()).getTime()`.

Everything works fine except for instances where the time difference is between 0-100ms. Here I get a massive negative numbers such as -17,183,398,582. Does anyone know what is causing this? Is it got to do with the way Javascript is handling the date substraction or is it something to do with Analytics?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but that negative number sounds like it could be linked to [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time. Example:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
```

`currentTime` will hold a number such as `1289985468` which represents "GMT: Wed, 17 Nov 2010 09:17:48 GMT".

Perhaps there's a bug in that code you're using.